# Custom view in Android Gallery not working as it should

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

I have the following fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/breadCrumbsTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Inicio»"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:padding="0dp" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contenido_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/fragment_list_carrousel_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the gallery view I'm rendering the following custom view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gallery_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/previous" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_gallery_item_imageview"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_gallery_item_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gallery_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/next" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Everything works but imageview gallery_left and gallery_right are not in the correct place, I would like them to be next to the left / right margins, what should I do?